# How to make a progress indicator work in ParallelTable mode in Mathematica?

Tags: parallelization, monitoring

I developed a code to display a progress bar, percentage and time dynamically when I am running a plot that calculates things (using user defined function called computethings).  It works nicely in serial mode or when I am using Table function.  However, in parallel mode (2 kernels or threads) or using ParallelTable function, only time display works.  The progress bar and percentage does not work.  I tried other examples in stackexchange but it does not work in my code that works fine in serial mode.  Obviously, a function called ProgressIndicator does not work.   Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Below is a sample code:

```
ac = 2;
bc = 2;
acstep = 0.1;
bcstep = 0.1;
test = 10;

answer[newu_, newv_] :=
NDSolve[{u'[t] == newu + v[t]*Sin[t + u[t]],
v'[t] == newv*u[t]*newv*Cos[t + v[t]], u[0] == newu,
v[0] == newv}, {u, v}, {t, test - 5, test + 5},
Method -> Automatic];

goldmine = {{9, 11}, {-11, -9}};

closeanswer = Nearest[goldmine -> Automatic] /* First;

computethings[startu_, startv_] :=
closeanswer[{u[test], v[test]} /. answer[startu, startv] // Flatten,
1];

SetAttributes[ShowProgress,HoldAll];

ShowProgress[a_,
{i_,min_,max_}]:=With[{progressStartTime=AbsoluteTime[]},Monitor[a,Dynamic[Refresh[Row[{Pro
gressIndicator[Dynamic[i],{min,max}],{((i+Abs[min])/(max-min)*100)//N,"%
",duration=N[AbsoluteTime[]-progressStartTime],"seconds"}}//Flatten," "],UpdateInterval→0.25]]]]

ShowProgress[
ArrayPlot[
Table[computethings[x, y], {x, -ac, ac, acstep}, {y, -bc, bc, bcstep}],
ColorRules -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Brown}], {x, -ac, ac}]
```

while calculating the answer, it shows this :

[image: tableindicator]

Once completed, it plots goldmine:

[image: answer]

Running again but using ParallelTable or:

```
ShowProgress[
ArrayPlot[
ParallelTable[computethings[x, y], {x, -ac, ac, acstep}, {y, -bc, bc, bcstep}],
ColorRules -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Brown}], {x, -ac, ac}]
```

while calculating the answer, it shows this:

[image: paralleltableindicator]

The progress indicator is not active.  The percentage is not active.  However, the timing runs fine.

The output is the same as before or :

[image: answer]

Like I mentioned before, the culprit is probably Dynamic[i].  I attempted defining i as shared variable but still I made no progress.

Comment: there's a question on this every couple of months, but no compromise free solution https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=monitor+paralleltable

Comment: I think there's something for ParallelMap in Wolfram Funcions Repository but I don't have time to search for it atm.

Comment: @Kuba [`ResourceFunction["ParallelMapMonitored"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ParallelMapMonitored)

Comment: @flinty , thanks for response.  Your suggestions require a complete rewrite of the code that partially works.  I am trying to avoid that.  I know that the source of trouble in my code when ParallelTable is used instead Table is in the ProgressIndicator code line. More specifically, Dynamic[i].  the variable i is not incremented in ParallelTable mode.

Comment: @ Szabolcs, thanks for links, I looked into them and so far can't figure it out.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for response.  I do not see how ParallelMap will help me avoid a complete rewrite of my existing code.  See comment I made for flinty.

Comment: Try `DynamicMap`from the ResourceFunction repository and use the parable option

Answer (score 5):

As **@Kuba** mentioned there is a `ResourceFunction` called `ParallelMapMonitored` available in the functions repository. Here's an example I concocted that uses it:

```
computethings[x_, y_] := x*y;
{ac, bc} = {1, 1};
{acstep, bcstep} = {.005, .005};
ParallelMapMonitored = ResourceFunction["ParallelMapMonitored"];
grid = Table[{x, y}, {x, -ac, ac, acstep}, {y, -bc, bc, bcstep}];
result = ParallelMapMonitored[computethings @@ # &, Flatten[grid, 1]];
result = ArrayReshape[result, Most[Dimensions[grid]]];
MatrixPlot@result
```

Unfortunately it doesn't have a level argument, so you cannot shorten this code much. This example below that should square all elements in a 100x100 matrix of random numbers won't work:

```
ParallelMapMonitored[#^2 &, RandomReal[1, {100, 100}], {2}]
```

Comment: flinty, there’s also [`MonitorProgress`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MonitorProgress), it might be valuable to include this in your answer also.

Comment: @CATrevillian The parallel examples there do not work for me. `MonitorProgress[Parallelize@Table[x^2, {x, -10, 10, 0.05}]]` fails in 12.1.1 saying `MonitorProgress::injectFailed` as does `MonitorProgress[ParallelTable[x^2, {x, -10, 10, 0.05}]]` as does `MonitorProgress[Table[$KernelID, 20], 
 Parallelization -> {Method -> "FinestGrained"}]` and it returns all zeros.

Comment: Must be new issue with 12.1.1 then, I thought I had done it with 12.0 at least. Hopefully Lukas Lang can see this somehow